# How to create customizer menu and create a field in my WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress

When I go to dashboard > Appearance > Customize of my WordPress site (One custom theme installed in my WordPress site) I see there are many custom section  added.

[image]
[image]

Again when I go to those section I see that there is some custom section also and can add new field also.

How can I add those custom section in wordpress Customizer and how can I create "add new field" (same as our service section images) option?

Comment: What theme and plugins are you using?

Comment: I see from parallax one WordPress theme link :http://themeisle.com/demo/?theme=Parallax%20One
But i want to create this type of custom menu and add new field in my new WordPress theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API - details the Customization API. SitePoint has a good tutorial at http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-with-the-wordpress-theme-customization-api/